# Will a JS root view always receive events from native after it has been removed from its superview?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

My (heavily simplified) code looks like this:

```
// objc
self.currentSwipeUpView = [[RCTRootView alloc]
   initWithBridge:_bridge moduleName:@"PhotoSwipeUpView"
   initialProperties:nil
];
// elsewhere...
[self.currentSwipeUpView removeFromSuperview];
self.currentSwipeUpView = nil;

// js
function PhotoSwipedUpView() {
    return <TextInput style={{flex: 1}} onChangeText={console.warn} />
}
AppRegistry.registerComponent('PhotoSwipeUpView', () => PhotoSwipeUpView)
```

`self.currentSwipeUpView` is removed from its superview and dereferenced. When this happen, is it possible for the JS thread to not receive a pending onChangeText event? Would it lead to `console.warn` to being with the new text?

I'm imagining a case where the event would have been sent to the JS thread after the RCTRootView was removed from its superview and dereferenced.

Furthermore, I'm curious if it's possible to be notified when a RCTRootView is removed from its superview from the JS side.

I'm using ARC and I'm not holding any other references to `self.currentSwipeUpView`.

**Edit:** I have two RCTRootViews. Only one of them will be unloaded, the other will persist across the state of the application. They use the same bridge, and therefore use the same bundle and JS environment.

Answer (score 0):

**Loading/Unloading JS Bundles**

Your loaded js bundle is tied to the root view and is not persistent other than in that view.
Once you remove the root view from it's parent, the bundle is also unloaded. If the root view is removed and dereferenced, the text change listeners should also be removed and should not trigger.

The JSX in the bundle is used to ultimately setup native elements plus their listeners. The JSX is basically the script. The JSX with a RN `TextInput` basically results in a native `UITextField`. If the JSX specifies a listener, then a native listener for text changes is added to the native element instance.

Even if you had two root views loaded, they would operate independently from each other. If one root view is unloaded, the listeners associated with the TextInputs on the screen should no longer receive events. Your second Root View should be unaffected as it would have separate listeners setup for the TextInput.

**Events/Timing issue**

I suppose there is a small chance with perfect timing, and depending on where the removeFromSuperview is called, that the js could just receive the event before the view is completely removed and dereferenced, but if that has a possibility of affecting the functionality of your app, I would suggest using another pattern to interact with your data and remove the screen.

**Possible Solution**

It's hard to say without knowing what you're trying to do, but you could, for example, post a notification to close the React Native view using `RCTEventEmitter`/`NativeEventEmitter`, then have the React Native screen close itself with a native function that just removes it from the super view. This type of pattern would also answer your second question (in a sense), because you're effectively telling the RN screen before it should close allowing it to take any actions necessary before being removed.

Comment: Hi, I've added some details to my question in response to your answer. I have two RCTRootViews that use the same bridge and bundle.

Comment: where and how do you use the other view? also, what is the issue that you're facing?

Comment: did you see my edit? This question is mostly theoretical, my actual app has a RCTRootView created by a native view, which is created by a RCTRootView which is the top-level view for the app. The native view implements a list.

Comment: updated my answer to explain a bit more about the JSX-Native relationship

Comment: So, two RCTRootViews with the same bridge and bundle have separate JS environments? (Separate as in separate global state, separate JS singletons etc.)

Comment: I believe so. I have an app that does this flow: Native -> RN -> Native -> RN. In my case, I have a native feed where a user can view posts. When they click on a post, it launches a RN view to see the post details. From the post details, they can click on a user who left a comment, which launches a native view (User Profile screen). From the User Profile screen, they can click on one of those user's posts, which launches a new RN view. My RN views have text inputs for comments and other things, and I've never seen an issue or conflict with the state or input listeners.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176297/discussion-between-nohtyyzar-and-jeremy-lee).